# Hay alguna manera de poner codigo php en contact form 7 para realizar mi trackin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo unas Landing Page en código html, ahora estoy pensando en pasarlas a wordpress, en los contact.php tengo un código php que coge unos valores, me gustaría saber si yo al pasarlo a wordpress esos códigos php que tengo en el contact.php puedo ponerlos en el plugin contact form 7 de wordpress?

Os pongo el codigo que tengo en contact.php que utilizamos composer

```
<?php
// Composer's auto-loading functionality
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

//

 $nombreAplicacion = "XXXX";
 $direccionCorreo = "XXXXXXX";
 $idCliente = "XXXXX";

// Nombre del SpreadSheet creada
 $nombreSpreahSheet = "Php Sheet volcado";
 // Nombre de hoja de cálculo
 $hojaCalculo = "Hoja 2";

 $scope = array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds');

 // Inicializamos Google Client
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setApplicationName($nombreAplicacion);
 $client->setClientId($idCliente);

 // credenciales, scope y archivo p12. Agregar el correcto Path al archivo p12
 $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
 $direccionCorreo,
 $scope,
 file_get_contents('PhpSheet-3a5bbd2c9ada.p12')
);

 $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

 // si expiro el access token generamos otro
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
 $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

// Obtenemos el access token
$obj_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
$accessToken = $obj_token->access_token;

 // Inicializamos google-spreadsheet-client
 $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
 ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

 //Obtenemos los Spreadsheets disponibles para las credenciales actuales
 $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
 $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();

// Obtenemos la spreadsheet por su nombre
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($nombreSpreahSheet);

// Obtenemos las hojas de cálculo de la spreadsheet obetenida
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();

// Obtenemos la hoja de cálculo por su nombre
 $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($hojaCalculo);
 $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

 if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre'])) {
 $dataAgregar = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid'],
 'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP
 );
  $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar);
 }
 if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre2'])) {
  $dataAgregar2 = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid2'],
 'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre2'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email2'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone2'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje2'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP2
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar2);
 }   
 ?>
```

Como tenemos que utilizar composer en la carpeta del theme he de subir un index.php, una carpeta de vendor y unos archivos composer, como en el theme ya tenemos un index.php no se si tambien sirve coger el codigo el index.php e introducirlo en el index.php del theme para que funcione composer?

Comment: ¿Qué significa LP?

Comment: LP significa ->Landing Page

Answer (score 2):

Podrías añadir en el functions.php el siguiente código:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'mi_funcion');

function mi_funcion($cf7) {
    //Código PHP
}
```

La manera de tratar las variables de envío es accediendo a la variable  `$_POST['nombre_de_mi_campo']` donde `'nombre_de_mi_campo'` se corresponde con el nombre definido en el formulario de contact form 7. Sólo te faltaría añadir tu código ligeramente modificado para acceder a las variables correctamente dentro de la función.

**Edito la respuesta porque has editado la pregunta**

Bueno, de repente estamos hablando de composer, poco te puedo decir al respecto, una manera de utilizarlo es creando un directorio en la ruta `"themes/mi_tema/directorio"` donde alojar todo lo necesario, así cuando ejecutes `"composer install"` te creará el directorio vendor e instalará en él las dependencias que especificas en el json (creo que es así).

Una vez has hecho esto, añade la siguiente línea en `functions.php` o en `wp-config.php`:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

y ya debería funcionar.

Comentas que te arroja un error 500, esto en `wordpress` puede ocurrir por falta de memoria en `PHP` o por un error en el `htaccess`.

Comment: A ver si te he entendido bien, en el functions.php añado el codigo que me has pasado y dentro de mi function añado el codigo que tengo yo en mi contact.php? tengo una variable que es la de coger la url de donde proviene y esto se hace en el contact.php segun html, aqui en wordpress como lo haria o donde lo pondria?

Comment: Esta línea add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'mi_funcion');  hace que se ejecute la función 'mi_funcion' justo antes de que el formulario envíe los datos por correo, así que, todo lo que escribas en la función 'mi_funcion' funcionará (o por lo menos debería). Tienes que tener en cuenta que escribes en php así que si capturabas la url usando $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] te seguirá funcionando.

Comment: Vale, el problema es el siguiente; el php que utilizo necesita vendor y composer, y cuando pongo el php en la funcion me da error 500, el porque no lo se, lo suyo seria que funcionara como decis asi no tengo que instalar ningn plugin, voy a editar la pregunta a poner el codigo y los archivos que he de subir al theme que son los de composer.

Comment: Yo esta función la tengo al terminar mi contac.php no al principio

Comment: Gracias @ErnestoRM Composer ya lo subo instalado a /wp-content/mi_tema/ ahi subo el fichero vendor, el composer.php y composer.json con y el fichero p12 de google sheet.La linea que me dices que inserte es para que funcione vendor verdad? Pero yo sa linea la tengo dentro de mi php que he de poner en el functions.php verdad? El error 500 que me da wordpress es porque utilizo use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory; Es por ello que me da ese error. como lo soluciono?

Comment: He conseguido que no me de error 500, he desplaado el use fuera de la funcion mi_funcion y de momento no me da error, ahora voy a comprobar que funcione todo el php que he realizado para insertar los datos en google sheet

Comment: He conseguido introducir el codigo php que tengo en mi contact.php en el functions.php sin que de error, que sucede ahora, cuando tengo el codigo introducido voy al formulario a realizar una prueba y en vez de que me salga el mensaje de su mensaje se ha enviado correctamente de contact form 7 se queda las flechas dando vueltas y miro la consola de google chrome y me da unos errores en jquery.

Comment: Perdonar por tantos comentarios. Si la funcion la añado antes de enviar el mail me da error 500 si la funcion lo añado despues de enviar el mail no me da error 500, pero no se me añaden los registros en el sheet, lo he probado de la manera tradicional, hacer un form normal y hacerlo a traves de contact.php y asi si funciona pero con contact form 7 no me funciona.

Comment: Si la función se dispara después del envío del mail, funciona correctamenrte pero manda los datos vacíos ¿es por la volatilidad de los datos? es decir ¿lo solucionarías almacenando los datos en alguna variable más persistente? como $_SESSION o guardándolos en la BD. Pruébalo y nos comentas. Y llegados a este punto  yo me plantearía si sale rentable seguir usando contact form 7 o es mejor añadir el formulario "a mano". Un saludo.

Comment: Antes tenia yo $SESSION pero como me comentaron que tenia que ser con $POST[nomre del campo] ya que el sesion_start(); donde lo he de añadir?

Comment: ¿Has consguido hacer que funcione @Aitor?

Comment: Pues solo lo he conseguido  haciendo un formulario de contacto con codigo, pero con contact form 7 no y ademas ahora el sheet me da un error que no lo entiendo, me dice Estas filas exceden los límites. Hago la prueba en un sheet de prueba y funciona correctamente